# How to use import inside eslintrc file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to use imported object to setup some restrictions for globals  inside .eslintrc.js file, but import doesnt work. How can i make dynamic eslint config?

```
import {loadedGlobals} from '@/util/globals'                      

module.exports = {
    'globals': Object.keys(loadedGlobals).reduce((acum, key) => {
        acum[key] = false
        return acum
    }, acum),
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

With the [new configuration system](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#configuration-file) you can use an `eslint.config.js` file with `"type": "module"` in your package.json to support `import` statements.

Additionally, if you need to load an ESM module from a CJS context, the configuration file can export a promise, so you can run `await import` inside an `async` function.

```js
async function config () {
  const dep = await import('esm-dep')
  return [dep]
}
module.exports = config()
```

The ability to export a promise is currently supported, just not documented yet. The [updated docs have been merged](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/17301/files#diff-0cf081f8462b9c64db87ffb11f778815a0f61740773c73b0b57fd29664302b1dR47), just not published yet.

There is also the hidden gem of the [`-c eslint.config.mjs`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/16864#issuecomment-1421248234) approach for node versions that support module system context via file extensions.

**Original:**

> How to use import inside eslintrc file?

ESLint currently doesn't support a configuration file by the name of `eslintrc` so I'm going to assume you mean `.eslintrc.js`.

ESLint currently does not support ES Modules as you can see from the **JavaScript (ESM)** bullet item on their [configuration file formats](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats) documentation.

If you are willing to install another dependency here is how you can use `import` inside of `.eslintrc.js`:

1. Install the [`esm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) module, `npm i esm -D` (Here I'm choosing as a `devDependency`).
2. Create a new file as a sibling to `.eslintrc.js` called `.eslintrc.esm.js`.
3. Inside of `.eslintrc.esm.js` include your ESLint configuration. Here you can use `import` and you should export your configuration as `export default { // Your config }`.
4. Inside `.eslintrc.js` include the following code:

```js
const _require = require('esm')(module)
module.exports = _require('./.eslintrc.esm').default
```

Now you should be able to run `eslint` as usual. A bit clunky with the extra file, but you can organize them in a directory if you like and use the `--config` option of `eslint` to point to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

You might notice that you are using the old syntax when exporting your object. You could try using `require()` instead of import.

Alternatively, you could look into [Shareable Configs](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs).