# Vue 3 on Vite.js with Eslint — Unable to resolve path to module eslint(import/no-unresolved)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, vite, eslintrc

I use Vue 3 on Vite.js with Eslint + Airbnb config. Airbnb config has a rule `eslint(import/no-unresolved)`, which is good, but Eslint doesn't know how to resolve alias path.

I want to use aliases for paths — example:
`import TableComponent from '@/components/table/TableComponent.vue'˙`

Environment is in plain JavaScript.

I managed to set up my `vite.config.js` so that the app can resolve paths like this:

```
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{
        find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      },],
  },
});
```

Vue app works like that and resolves the import path correctly, but Eslint keeps reporting the error: `Unable to resolve path to module eslint(import/no-unresolved)`

How and where can I tell Eslint how to resolve aliases?

I have tried:
`install eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-alias --save-dev`

```
// .eslintrc.js

// ...
extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'airbnb-base',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
],

settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['@', 'src'],
        ],
      },
    },
  },
```

But that doesn't work.

---

EDIT:
Solved the issue, see the accepted answer if you're using plain JavaScript like I do.

If you're using TypeScript, see if [Seyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69640843/12648269) can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone runs into this problem, this works in my case*:

```
settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['@', './src'],
        ],
      },
    },
  },
```

*In my case, Vue's root is 'src' directory, while Eslint's is one level higher, so it needs the './src' path.

Huge thanks to @https://github.com/aladdin-add for the answer through the github question!

Comment: This didn't work for me, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @JCraine check your project's folder structure. I've put a note (asterisk, *) on that issue. It could also be your OS reading path differently, but it's beyond my knowledge if that could affect it. If you're looking for TypeScript solution, check Syed's answer.

Answer (score 17):

this solves the issue in my `TypeScript` project.

```
npm install eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

After `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` installation

```
{
  // other configuration are omitted for brevity
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      typescript: {} // this loads <rootdir>/tsconfig.json to eslint
    },
  },
}
```

should be added to `.eslintrc.js.`

my tsconfig.json (remove unwanted settings)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "node"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Check the discussion [here](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1485#issuecomment-535351922):

Comment: I don't use TS, and I've resolved it with different `path` ('./src' instead of 'src') as I've shown in the answer.

Comment: @DeliciousBacon this answer was for the users who come in search of `TS` fix :)

Comment: You should update your answer and state it "solves the issue when using TypeScript" because "this solves the issue." is vague. I'll mention it in the OP.

Comment: @DeliciousBacon yes, just did that. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I can't for the life of me get this to work, I've tried everything above. Is there something else wrong with my file?

```js
// .eslintrc.cjs
/* eslint-env node */
require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution");

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },

  // Using the accepted answer
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      alias: {
        map: [["@", "./src"]],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

### ** UPDATE **

The only way I was able to get this to work was using this: `eslint-config-airbnb` [link here](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-airbnb/tree/main/packages/eslint-config-airbnb#readme), the readme was particularly helpful.

`npm add --dev @vue/eslint-config-airbnb @rushstack/eslint-patch`

My **.eslintrc.js** is now:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution");

const path = require("node:path");
const createAliasSetting = require("@vue/eslint-config-airbnb/createAliasSetting");

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb", // <-- added
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },

  rules: {
    "import/no-unresolved": "error",
  },
  settings: {
    ...createAliasSetting({
      "@": `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")}`,
    }),
  },
};
```

Huzzah!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and even I fixed the src path it still hat the issue. It did not work until I added extensions:

```
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": {
        "map": [
          ["@", "./src"]
        ],

        "extensions": [".js",".jsx"] <--- HERE
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Use & export aliases in vite.config.js**

```js
// vite.config.js

import { resolve } from 'path';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export const aliases = {
    '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    '@u': resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
};

export default () => defineConfig({
  // ...
  resolve: {
      alias: aliases,
  },
})
```

**2. Create .eslintrc with ES Modules support.** (Thanks to [Morgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68552441/12496886))

2.1 `npm i esm -D`

2.2 Create sibling to `.eslintrc.js` — `.eslintrc.esm.js`.

2.3 Put your your ESLint config into `.eslintrc.esm.js`.

```js
// .eslintrc.esm.js

export default {
  root: true,
  extends: ['@vue/airbnb', 'plugin:vue/recommended'],
  // ...
}
```

2.4 Inside `.eslintrc.js` include this code:

```js
const _require = require('esm')(module)
module.exports = _require('./.eslintrc.esm.js').default
```

**3. Import, map & use aliases from `vite.config.js` in `.eslintrc.esm.js`**

3.1 `npm i eslint-import-resolver-alias -D`

3.2 Inside `.eslintrc.esm.js` include following code:

```js
// .eslintrc.esm.js

import { aliases } from './vite.config';

const mappedAliases = Object.entries(aliases).map((entry) => entry); // [[alias, path], [alias, path], ...]

export default {
  // ...
  settings: {
      'import/resolver': {
          alias: {
              map: mappedAliases,
          },
      },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `README.md` of [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import#resolvers) it is said:

> Currently [Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node) and [webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-webpack) resolution have been implemented, but the resolvers are just npm packages, so [third party packages are supported](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/wiki/Resolvers) (and encouraged!).

[Here](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/wiki/Resolvers) you can see the list of the third party resolvers.

One that worked for me was this: [eslint-import-resolver-custom-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-custom-alias), and this is how I used it:

```yaml
settings:
  import/resolver:
    eslint-import-resolver-custom-alias:
      alias:
        '@': './app/javascript'
      extensions:
        - '.js'
        - '.vue'
```

For me the `@` had been set as an alias for `app/javascript` inside `vite.config.ts`, you should change this based on your project configurations.

Answer (score 0):

in .eslintrc.js add

```
settings: {
'import/resolver': {
  alias: {
    map: [['@', './src/']],
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
  },
},
```

},