# TS Config nested alias for absolute path not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm trying to set up path aliases in my `tsconfig.json` for a React app bundled with Vite. Here is the relevant part of my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    ...
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*", "node_modules/*"],
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "containers/*": ["src/containers/*"],
      "pages/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "store/*": ["src/store/*"],
      "types/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "NestedFolder/*": [
        "src/components/NestedFolder/*"
      ],
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "*"]
}
```

The only issue is with the `NestedFolder`. When I import this way, everything works:

```js
import { ComponentName } from "components/NestedFolder/types";
```

However, the nested alias fails:

```js
import { ComponentName } from "NestedFolder/types";

// error 
EslintPluginImportResolveError: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolver
Occurred while linting .../src/components/NestedFolder/canvas/index.ts:1
Rule: "import/namespace"

// error on hover in VS Code
Unable to resolve path to module 'NestedFolder/types'.eslintimport/no-unresolved
```

I would like to do nested components because I have several folders that are nested 3-4 levels and it would be nice to have a cleaner view of my imports. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I assume you have tried restarting your TS server if you are using VSCode. I recommend using [vite-tsconfig-paths plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths) and see if this works

Comment: I restarted my server, VS Code, and ran the build command, and the build breaks as is. Thanks, I'll look into the plugin. I was hoping to avoid adding additional libraries/plugins, but that may be my only choice now.

Comment: Update: the plugin did solve my issue, thank you!

Comment: No problem! I will make my comment an answer so it's more clear for others that may need to find this plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [vite-tsconfig-paths plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths) to set up path aliases using TypeScript and Vite.
If nothing changes and you are using VSCode make sure to restart the TypeScript server by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd+Shift+P`, typing `restart`, and then selecting the command: `TypeScript: Restart TS server`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. I found that I had to install the following packages:

`npm i eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-alias eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

And then add the following configurations, with the important ingredient being strongly-defined alias paths:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  root: true, // important to ensure nested eslint scoping in monorepos
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
  extends: [
    'airbnb-typescript-prettier',
    'plugin:import/typescript'
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: path.join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
    tsconfigRootDir: './src',
  },
  settings: {
    "import/parsers": { // add this definition
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          // define each alias here
          ['components', path.join(__dirname, './src/components')],
        ],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
      },
      typescript: {
        project: path.join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I think this could be improved on by harmonizing the aliases between the .eslintrc and vite.config so aliases only need to be defined once, using a tactic like the one defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908814/14198287

Answer (score 0):

if [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths) is not working for you. Make sure you didn't install `v4.0.0`. That version has a bug.

`v4.0.1` fix it.

Install with the following:

```bash
npm install vite-tsconfig-paths@latest
```

Should install `v4.0.1` at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be improved on by harmonizing the aliases between the .eslintrc and vite.config so aliases only need to be defined once, using a tactic like the one defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908814/14198287

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).